# I need help filtering bad words in C?

Tags: c, string, filter, string-matching

As you can see, I am trying to filter various bad words. I have some code to do so. I am using C, and also this is for a GTK application.

```
char LowerEnteredUsername[EnteredUsernameLen];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < EnteredUsernameLen; i++) {
    LowerEnteredUsername[i] = tolower(EnteredUsername[i]);
}
LowerEnteredUsername[EnteredUsernameLen+1] = '\0';
if (strstr(LowerEnteredUsername, (char[]){LetterF, LetterU, LetterC, LetterK})||strstr(LowerEnteredUsername, (char[]){LetterF, LetterC, LetterU, LetterK})) {
    gtk_message_dialog_set_markup((GtkMessageDialog*)Dialog, "This username seems to be innapropriate.");
    UsernameErr = 1;
}
```

My issue is, is that, it will only filter the last bad word specified in the if statement. In this example, "fcuk". If I input "fuck," the code will pass that as clean. How can I fix this?

Comment: `tolower` will not work for most Unicode characters. You need a Unicode library like ICU for that purpose

Comment: If this is C, then `strstr(LowerEnteredUsername, "fcuk")` works too, no need for the verbose C#-looking syntax

Comment: @smac89 I have defined each variable for each letter to avoid explicit bad words in the code/compilled code

Comment: @phuclv Although this is not shown, I filter any username that contains anything other than alphabetical letters, numerals, and underscores

Comment: Seems impossible that it works for one and not for the other seeing as they are being checked in the same way. As a sidenote, you are writing to memory that you don't have access to when you do `LowerEnteredUsername[EnteredUsernameLen+1] = '\0';`

Comment: @smac89 I have heard that `strlen()` does not include the nulterm. That is my reasoning. Also there would be a segfault if I tried writting to memery I cannot access

Comment: `strlen` only works with null terminated strings. Also it is not neccessarily the case that if you don't get segfault in C, then everything is dandy. Writing to memory you don't have access has undefined behavior and if your program is not crashing now doesn't mean it is A-Ok

Comment: @smac89 All the strings I work with are null terminated, so it does apply

Comment: Except in this case, `LowerEnteredUsername` is not null terminated, atleast not in the true meaning of the phrase "null terminated string". Also note the warning given for [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr): **The behavior is undefined if either str or substr is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.** My guess is that your problem hinges on you trying to get away with undefined behaviour and C is just allowing you, but that's all it can do. You should perhaps try to compile your program with the `-pedantic` flag

Comment: @smac89 what is really peculiar is why is it the last one that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (char[]){LetterF, LetterU, LetterC, LetterK}
> ```

> ```
> (char[]){LetterF, LetterC, LetterU, LetterK}
> ```

You’ve forgotten to terminate your strings with a `'\0'`. This approach doesn’t seem to me to be very effective in keeping ~bad words~ out of source code, so I’d really suggest just writing regular string literals:

```
if (strstr(LowerEnteredUsername, "fuck") || strstr(LowerEnteredUsername, "fcuk")) {
```

Much clearer. If this is really, truly a no-go, then some other indirect but less error-prone ways are:

```
"f" "u" "c" "k"
```

or

```
#define LOWER_F "f"
#define LOWER_U "u"
#define LOWER_C "c"
#define LOWER_K "k"
```

and

```
LOWER_F LOWER_U LOWER_C LOWER_K
```

Comment: I have found this online game, ruthless conquest, and I decided to decompile it. Inside the decompiled code, I found a file which was basically just a list of every bad word imaginable. I am not allowed to use string literals. So, I am going to try your first suggestion of not forgetting to terminate the strings. Thanks

Comment: Thanks this answer was usefull

Answer (score 1):

Doing human-language text processing in C is painful because C's concept of strings (i.e. `char*`/`char[]` and `wchar_t*`/`wchar_t[]`) are very low-level and are not expressive enough to *easily* represent Unicode text, let alone locate word-boundaries in text and match words in a known dictionary (also consider things like inflection, declension, plurals, the use of diacritics to evade naive string matching).

For example - your program would need to handle George carlin's famous *Seven dirty words* quote:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbZhpf3sQxQ
>
> Someone was quite interested in these words. They kept referring to them: they called them bad, dirty, filthy, foul, vile, vulgar, coarse, in poor taste, unseemly, street talk, gutter talk, locker room language, barracks talk, bawdy, naughty, saucy, raunchy, rude, crude, lude, lascivious, indecent, profane, obscene, blue, off-color, risqué, suggestive, cursing, cussing, swearing... and all I could think of was: shit, piss, fuck, cunt, cocksucker, motherfucker, and tits!

This could be slightly modified to evade a naive filter, like so:

> Someone was quite interested in these words. They kept referring to them: they called them bad, dirty, filthy, foul, vile, vulgar, coarse, in poor taste, unseemly, street talk, gutter talk, locker room language, barracks talk, bawdy, naughty, saucy, raunchy, rude, crude, lude, lascivious, indecent, profane, obscene, blue, off-color, risqué, suggestive, cursing, cussing, swearing... and all I could think of was: shít, pis$, phuck, c​unt, сocksucking, motherfúcker, and títs!

Above, some of the words have simple replacements done, like `s` to `$`, others had diacritics added like `u` to `ú`, and some are just [homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)), however some of the other words in the above *look the same* but actually contain [homographs](https://www.irongeek.com/homoglyph-attack-generator.php) or "invisible" characters like Unicode's zero-width-space, so they would evade naive text matching systems.

So in short: Avoid doing this in C. if you must, then use a robust and fully-featured Unicode handling library (i.e. do not use the C Standard Library's string functions like `strstr`, `strtok`, `strlen`, etc).

Here's how I would do it:

1. Read in input to a binary blob containing Unicode text (presumably UTF-8).
2. Use a Unicode library to:

   1. Normalize the encoded Unicode text data (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence )
   2. Identify word boundaries (assuming we're dealing with European-style languages that use sentences comprised of words).
   3. Use a linguistics library and database (English alone is full of special-cases) to normalize each word to some singular canonical form.
   4. Then lookup each morpheme in a case-insensitive hash-set of known "bad words".

Now, there are a few shortcuts you can take:

- You can use regular-expressions to identify word-boundaries.
- There exist Unicode-aware regular-expression libraries for C, for example PCRE2: http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2unicode.html
- You can skip normalizing each word's inflections/declensions if you're happy with having to list those in your "bad word" list.

I would write working code for this example, but I'm short on time tonight (and it would be a LOT of code), but hopefully this answer provides you with enough information to figure out the rest yourself.

(Pro-tip: don't match strings in a list by checking each character - it's slow and inefficient. This is what hashtables and hashsets are for!)

Comment: I can't see why to explicitly filter words like "fucking," "motherfucker," and stuff like that as they already contain "fuck," so the filter would filter them anyways

Comment: Another thing about the temporary replacements is I have restricted the usernames to only allow the 26 alphabetical characters upper or lower case and numbers and underscores. I don't have to worry about filtering "FUcK" differently from "fuck" because as shown in the code I convert it to lower case anyway, prior to the filtering.

Comment: @noone Because then you'll run into the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem